# Problem in using pdfcrop

Tags: errors, pdf, windows, perl, pdfcrop

I am writing a LaTeX document on my Windows machine and I want to crop a pdf using `pdfcrop`. From my research I could learn that, I also have to install perl. I have downloaded and installed 64-bit [ActivePerl](https://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) on my computer. But that has not solved my purpose and I have receive following error

```
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!
```

How can I solve this issue?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem by installing Ghostscript.

If you are using Windows, then Perl and Ghostscript does not come along with that. If you want to crop a pdf using `pdfcrop`, then you have to install Perl and Ghostscript explicitly along with Tex. These softwares could be downloaded from

https://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads
https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Comment: On Mac:

`brew install ghostscript`

and in `~/.bash_profile`:

`export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.54.0/bin:$PATH"` (adjust the path to the directory)

and then either open a fresh shell or run `source ~/.bash_profile`.